# Help with inequality question based on the exponential series

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is a very old Year 12 (high school) exam question I can't quite figure out. It has three parts and I'm stuck on the last part. This is for my maths revision only:

1) write down the series for $e^x$ and deduce that for any positive $k$ and for any positive $x$ that $e^x > x^k/k!$. This is simple enough to show as each term in the expansion is positive.

2) Find a number $A$ (doesn't have to be the smallest possible value of $A$, or even be near it) such that $e^x>x^{10}$ for all $x>A$. Using part 1) if you find $A$ such that $A^k/k!>A^{10}$ then $e^x>x^{10}$ for all $x>A$ (is that right?). This gives $A^{k-10}>k!$ and putting $k=11$ gives $A>11!$. So, take $A=11!+1$.

3) Find a number $B$ such that $e^x>100x^{10}$ for all $x>B$. This is the part I'm stuck on. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply assume $B > 100$ then your part (3) reduces to finding $B > 100$ such that $e^x > x^{11}$ for $x > B$. This is probably not the way to find the smallest such $B$, but I think it's the easiest because it directly reduces to part (2) which you already solved.